# AlreadyAllocated calling waveOutOpen error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, naudio

```
 private void receiveAudio(object sender)
        {
            IPEndPoint senderEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            MemoryStream audioDataStream;
            BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider; 
            //RawSourceWaveStream receivedRawAudioData;          
            byte[] receivedAudioData;
            waveOutStream = new WaveOut();

            while (IsAudioTransferActive)
            {
                receivedAudioData = audioUDPClient.Receive(ref senderEP);               
                audioDataStream = new MemoryStream(receivedAudioData);                
                //receivedRawAudioData = new RawSourceWaveStream(audioDataStream, audioFormat);
                bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(audioFormat);
//How can I feed "audioDataStream " to "bufferedWaveProvider "
                waveOutStream.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
                waveOutStream.Play();
            } 
            waveOutStream.Stop();
            waveOutStream.Dispose();
        }
```

@Mark Heath :- As u said  I have tried using BufferedWaveProvider but how can i feed the bufferedWaveProvider with "audioDataStream "

Comment: Post the whole exception please.

Comment: @abatishchev:- MmException was unhandled. AlreadyAllocated calling waveOutOpen

Comment: I have a waveOut that plays inside a loop which receives data from a UDP socket. But unfortunately it throws an error after around 30secs saying "MemoryAllocationError calling waveOutOpen" or "MmException was unhandled. AlreadyAllocated calling waveOutOpen"

Comment: @abatishchev:-I have a waveOut that plays inside a loop which receives data from a UDP socket. But unfortunately it throws an error after around 30secs saying "MemoryAllocationError calling waveOutOpen" or "MmException was unhandled. AlreadyAllocated calling waveOutOpen"

Comment: Have you tried this: http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/350724 ?

Comment: @Adrian Faciu:- Its my colleague who posted that question. we tried to do in that way. Because of that answer were not clear to us we didnt get the solution.

Comment: @Mark Heath:-As u said I have tried using BufferedWaveProvider but how can i feed the "bufferedWaveProvider" with "audioDataStream ". Code is edited.

Answer (score 3):

You are constantly creating WaveOut objects inside your while loop that are not disposed, which is part of the issue. The best approach in this situation is to create a single WaveOut object and to feed it using a BufferedWaveProvider. Then as audio becomes available, write it into the BufferedWaveProvider.

Comment: As "Mark Heath" said I have tried using BufferedWaveProvider but how can i feed the "bufferedWaveProvider" with "audioDataStream "

Comment: I'm tackling the same problem. How did you get past it if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem when initializing new `WaveOut` objects with SineWaveProviders. I came across the idea of using something like a ringlist to swap the different provider's values (frequency and amplitude) as, at least in my case, I couldn't hear any difference above 5 constant sine waves. Furthermore, in my tests on different machines, using more than 6-7 `WaveOut` objects at once usually resulted in `MemoryAllocationError`s thus the ringlist. This is, what I came out with:

```
private Queue<SineWaveGenerator> generators;

// constructor
public Player()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var generator = new SineWaveGenerator();
        generator.Amplitude = 0.25f;

        generators.Enqueue(generator);
    }
}

// just a helper method
private SineWaveGenerator GetGenerator(int frequency)
{
    return generators.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Frequency == frequency);
}

private void Play(int frequency)
{
    var generator = GetGenerator(frequency);

    if (generator == null)
    {
        generator = generators.Dequeue(); // get generator from the top of the list
        generator.Frequency = GetFrequency(key); // modify the generator
        generators.Enqueue(generator); // and append it to the back
    }

    generator.Play();
}

private void Stop(int frequency)
{
    var generator = GetGenerator(frequency);

    if (generator != null)
    {
        generator.Stop();
    }
}
```

Note: The `SineWaveGenerator` initializes a new `WaveOut` in its constructor.