# Error:- MemoryAllocationError calling waveOutOpen while playing in Loop

Tags: wpf, naudio

I have a waveOut that plays inside a loop which receives data from
a UDP socket. But unfortunately it throws an error after around 30secs 
saying "MemoryAllocationError calling waveOutOpen".

I use the below code to achieve this

```
private void startAudioTransfer(bool startSending, IPAddress receipientIP, bool startReceiving, IPAddress senderIP)
        {
            if (IsAudioSupported)
            {
                IsAudioTransferActive = true;
                audioUDPClient = new UdpClient(audioPort);

                if (startSending)
                {
                    startRecording();

                    audioSender = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(sendAudio));
                    audioSender.Start(receipientIP);
                }

                if (startReceiving)
                {
                    audioReceiver = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(receiveAudio));
                    audioReceiver.Start(senderIP);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Audio Transfer is not supported by your computer", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.OK);
            }
        }
private void receiveAudio(object sender)
        {
            IPEndPoint senderEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            MemoryStream audioDataStream;
            RawSourceWaveStream receivedRawAudioData;
            byte[] receivedAudioData;

            while (IsAudioTransferActive)
            {
                receivedAudioData = audioUDPClient.Receive(ref senderEP);
                waveOutStream = new WaveOut();
                audioDataStream = new MemoryStream(receivedAudioData);
                receivedRawAudioData = new RawSourceWaveStream(audioDataStream, audioFormat);
                waveOutStream.Init(receivedRawAudioData);
                waveOutStream.Play();
            }
            waveOutStream.Stop();
            waveOutStream.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: You can edit your old question instead of posting a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113216/alreadyallocated-calling-waveoutopen-error

Comment: @Adrian Faciu: but nobody gives me an answer