# NAudio.dll AlreadyAllocated

Tags: c#, exception, naudio

Another question about 'NAudio'.

When I test my project for school (Space Invaders) I'm getting the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'NAudio.MmException' occurred in NAudio.dll
Additional information: AlreadyAllocated calling waveOutOpen
```

What can I do ... ?

Greets

Comment: So you searched for "AlreadyAllocated calling waveOutOpen" and followed Mark Heath's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113216/alreadyallocated-calling-waveoutopen-error)?

Comment: How many WaveOut objects are you creating? Are you disposing of them? In my experience, you should only create a single one over the lifetime of your application.

Comment: Ow yeah I've found it I suppose, I was missing the "()". My bad.